# Not able to access images from private repo

Tags: github, repository, token, personal-access-token

I'm trying to use images from private repository, but all my attempts gave me `Error 404` as result! After I searched for solution on SO, I found out that you need [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) to use images from your private repo outside of github. But when I tried accessing my image with this token (`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/account_name/repo_name/v1.0.0/images/727.jpg?token=ghp_XXXX`) I still got `Error 404`! How can I solve it?

Comment: @VLAZ obviously, but it doesn't solve my problem, since I DO have access to this repo, because I'm its creator, and this file DOES exist

Comment: I'm saying that a 404 means the system doesn't recognise it as a resource that exists. It might be due to a typo in the URL or maybe some other reason but I don't think it's the fault of the token.

Comment: @VLAZ Why can I access this file with THE SAME link when I'm loggined in then? Github gives you this error not only when this file/repo doesn't exist, but also when you don't have access to it